# Как в PostgreSQL проверить размер массива?

Tags: postgresql

Есть поле с типом `JSON` где по умолчанию прописано `'[]'::json`. В это поле записываются как числа, так и слова.

Хочу получить из таблицы записи, в которых это поле заполнено (то есть массив имеет один или более элементов).

Пытаюсь реализовать с использованием всяких `cardinality`, `array_length` и прочих, но ничего не выходит.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1):

JSON это JSON. Это не массив из других типов данных, а непосредственно тип данных. И функции для обработки [у него свои](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html).

Вам нужны функции json_array_length и jsonb_array_length, в зависимости от того JSON у вас или JSONB